# Появление текста у блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте! Есть такой код: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYaoWG

При наведении на блок, он увеличивается в высоту. Нужно чтобы текст был в блоке и изначально его не было видно, и только по мере увеличения блока текст появлялся.

Можно задействовать другой язык если нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, добавьте к `#live` свойство `overflow: hidden;`. Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hmzLttte/) с вашим кодом

Ну, или копайте в сторону jquery `.animate();`